# LAST_VALUE over window in FlinkSQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I would like to run following query

```
SELECT key, LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY key ORDER BY ts) AS value
  FROM [table]
 GROUP BY key, TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE)
```

I would expect that `LAST_VALUE` would return last value of each time window. Instead I get

```
 Expression 'value' is not being grouped
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

---

Edit 1: Tried something like

```
SELECT key, LAST_VALUE(value) OVER (PARTITION BY key, TUMBLE(ts, INTERVAL '5' MINUTE) ORDER BY ts) AS value
  FROM [table]
```

but got instead

```
Unsupported call: TUMBLE(TIMESTAMP(3) *ROWTIME*, INTERVAL SECOND(3) NOT NULL)
```

(also: I think this is not equivalent as now I probably get retract stream instead of append stream)

Comment: Do you need to use SQL ?

Comment: @DominikWosiński yes I do